# DynamoDB nested attribute querying support

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Does Amazon DynamoDB scan operation allow you to query on nested attributes of type `Array` or `Object`? For example,

```json
{
    Id: 206,
    Title: "20-Bicycle 206",
    Description: "206 description",
    RelatedItems: [
        341, 
        472, 
        649
    ],
    Pictures: {
        FrontView: "123", 
        RearView: "456",
        SideView: "789"
    }
}
```

Can I query on `RelatedItems[2]` or `Pictures.RearView` attributes?

Answer (score 36):

Yes, you can use a [Filter Expression](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryAndScan.html#FilteringResults), which is just like Condition Expression. The section that talks about [the functions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.SpecifyingConditions.html#ConditionExpressionReference.Functions) that you can use in these types of expressions mentions the following:

"For a nested attribute, you must provide its full path; for more information, see [Document Paths](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.AccessingItemAttributes.html#DocumentPaths)."

The [Document Paths](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.AccessingItemAttributes.html#DocumentPaths) reference has examples on how to reference nested attributes in [DynamoDB data types](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DataModel.html#DataModel.DataTypes) like List (what you are calling an array) and Map (what you are calling an object). Check out that reference for examples on how to do so:

- MyList[0]
- AnotherList[12]
- ThisList[5][11]
- MyMap.nestedField
- MyMap.nestedField.deeplyNestedField

Comment: A caution that when using nested attributes with ExpressionAttributeNames the syntax is a little different than one might expect - you have to define each part of the path as a separate attribute name and then combine them with a dot in the FilterExpression (e.g. #pr.#1star): https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ExpressionAttributeNames.html#Expressions.ExpressionAttributeNames.NestedAttributes

Answer (score 20):

Please note that in DyanomoDB `query` and `scan` are quite different (`scan` is a much costlier operation).  So while you can filter on both as pointed out by @coffeeplease; you can only query/index on:

> The key schema for the index. Every attribute in the index key schema must be a top-level attribute of type String, Number, or Binary. Other data types, including documents and sets, are not allowed ([ref](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/SecondaryIndexes.html)).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can by passing list or value.

```
data = table.scan(FilterExpression=Attr('RelatedItems').contains([1, 2, 3]) & Attr('Pictures.RearView').eq('1'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can query on nested attributes of type array or object using scan or query .

Reference for Python boto3: 
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/dynamodb.html#querying-and-scanning

Example: Suppose you want to find out records for which the `RearView" > 500` and second item of `RelatedItems" > 200`, you can do the following:

```
data = table.scan(
    FilterExpression=Attr('RelatedItems[1]').gt('200') & Attr('Pictures.RearView').gt('500'))
```

Comment: How to do this using DynamoDBScanExpression(Java)?