# Is it more efficient to organize data into multiple rows columns or tables in a RDS schema, or multiple dynamo DB tables?

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, schema, amazon-dynamodb

Using Node.JS, (Dynamo DB and Sequelize)

Hey there,

I'm trying to tackle the best way to schema the following statistical report data that needs to be tracked for long term scalability.  The original architect used a dynamoDB solution because it was No SQL, and we needed the flexibility to add data without being restricted by the schema.  However, he nested properties into column objects, requiring us to query the entire table, and then loop through the results checking each row individually to building the response based on the requested search query.

Here is an example `report` Object that was originally stored in dynamoDB

EXAMPLE 1

```
{
  "boolData": null,
  "datetime": 1490391013471,
  "eventData": [
    {
      "eventType": 0,
      "location": "-16.3, 2.1, -70.8",
      "timestamp": 1490391033260
    }
  ],
  "floatData": {
    "averageAltitude": 1.79624987,
    "averageSpeed": 0,
    "maxAltitude": 3.55,
    "scorePercent": 0,
    "topSpeed": 0
  },
  "intData": {
    "altitudeViolations": 0,
    "closeCalls": 0,
    "crashCount": 1,
    "distanceToNoFlyViolations": 0,
    "lostLineOfSightViolations": 0,
    "moduleId": 2010,
    "moduleStatus": 0,
    "resetCount": 0,
    "sceneId": 1007,
    "score": 0,
    "tooCloseOrAbovePersonViolations": 0
  },
  "longData": {
    "moduleCompleted": 1490391033260,
    "moduleStartTime": 1490391023584,
    "moduleTotalTime": 9676
  },
  "objecttype": 1,
  "stringData": {
    "name": "test",
    "grade": "F",
    "moduleName": "HorizontalFlight1",
    "sceneName": "BasicTraining"
  },
  "userid": 1
}
```

This is obviously not the best way to store the data for the reasons stated above, since if I wanted to know what the `averageAltitude` for all flights that took place in a specific module or scene, i'd have to query ALL the data, then loop through ALL the results and check the property nested in the `floatData` and `intData` and compare against the information requested in the query to build the response.

So my next thought was why not store all the data in its own column like in `EXAMPLE 2`?  The only downside I could see with this schema in dynamo DB is the maximum amount of data allowed in a row/item is 400KB, and since we don't know how much data we'll want to add in the future, this might have issues with scaling.  The solution would just be to limit the items returned, and paginate the response based on what we currently know an items size is, and dividing that by the 1mb scan cap.

EXAMPLE 2

```
{
  "boolData": null,
  "datetime": 1490391013471,
  "eventData": [
    {
      "eventType": 0,
      "location": "-16.3, 2.1, -70.8",
      "timestamp": 1490391033260
    }
  ],
  "averageAltitude": 1.79624987,
  "averageSpeed": 0,
  "maxAltitude": 3.55,
  "scorePercent": 0,
  "topSpeed": 0
  "altitudeViolations": 0,
  "closeCalls": 0,
  "crashCount": 1,
  "distanceToNoFlyViolations": 0,
  "droneId": 0,
  "lostLineOfSightViolations": 0,
  "moduleId": 2010,
  "moduleStatus": 0,
  "resetCount": 0,
  "sceneId": 1007,
  "score": 0,
  "tooCloseOrAbovePersonViolations": 0
  "moduleCompleted": 1490391033260,
  "moduleStartTime": 1490391023584,
  "moduleTotalTime": 9676
  "objecttype": 1,
  "name": "test",
  "grade": "F",
  "moduleName": "HorizontalFlight1",
  "sceneName": "BasicTraining"
  "userid": 1
}
```

The OTHER idea I was mulling over was to separate `intData`, `floatData`, `stringData`, and `eventData` into their own dynamo DB tables, with an index of `reportId` to associate them accordingly, and then construct the the response. However, I'm not sure if dynamo DB was designed for this association / relationship purpose, and i'm pretty sure that sort of association would be faster with an RDS which leads to my second proposal.

If I stored the `EXAMPLE 1` in an Aurora/MySQL RDS, and stringified the `intData`, `floatData`, `stringData`, and `eventData` to store them in their own respective `TEXT` or `BLOB` column for a `Reports` table,  i'm pretty sure the scalability would be drastically less efficient.  Stringifying the data adds all those extra bytes, even though it'd allow us to flexibly add and remove properties to track in those columns, we still can't do a query like `SELECT * REPORTS WHERE averageAltitude >= 1.5` since that would require me to do exactly what i'm already doing with the extra step of parsing the stringified JSON.  I'd query ALL the reports and iterate through them checking the `floatData` property averageAltitude, and then build my result.  So to circumvent that, creating RDS tables for `intData`, `floatData,` and `stringData` with the following schema (only showing intData example purposes)

intData

```
id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(191),
      allowNull: false
    },
    value: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false
    }
```

and then doing a Report.hasMany Association

```
db.Report.hasMany(db.IntData, {
  as: 'intData',
  foreignKey: 'reportId',
  constraints: false
});
```

seems like a pretty practical method that might work well since I could easily include the data on the query, and it would be agnostic to the amount of intData, floatData, inserted per report. Is this the most optimal method? This method would remove the dynamo DB tables all together, but certainly seems like it would be more optimal than storing the `intData`, `floatData`, etc. as JSON strings in `TEXT` columns.  I'm just not sure if in the long term this method is more scalable for cost effective purposes then using dynamo DB.  We would like to postpone upgrading to a Large RDS for as long as possible, and querying reports is definitely going to be the most expensive call.

I appreciate your recommendations and input.  And please let me know of an alternative solution if I'm completely missing one that could be even better than the ones I propose.  Thank you!

Comment: I don't know if migrating is an option, but within noSQL, I know that querying nested properties in a schema is trivial, and you don't have to prefetch an entire collection to do a proper query. MongoDB, CouchDB, etc.

Comment: Hey @PatrickRoberts thanks for your quick response.  Migrating is an option.  I didn't know querying nested properties in noSQL is trivial, and perhaps the the original architect was doing it incorrectly.  I did come across this stack overflow question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32235474/dynamodb-nested-query-support  .  I'll see if fixing the queries to use the FilterExpression speeds things up.  I'd still like to know if based on the statistical data we're tracking, no SQL is the ideal direction to go.

Comment: For that specific question, my expertise is probably not enough to go on. I've never benchmarked performance between SQL and noSQL solutions for any particular project.