# How to query DynamoDB filtering by value in a list

Tags: javascript, python, typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

There are three items in database:

```
[
  {
    "year": 2013,
    "info": {
      "genres": ["Action", "Biography"]
    }
  },
  {
    "year": 2013,
    "info": {
      "genres": ["Crime", "Drama", "Thriller"]
    }
  },
  {
    "year": 2013,
    "info": {
      "genres": ["Action", "Adventure", "Sci-Fi", "Thriller"]

    }
  }
]
```

With the `year` attribute being the table's Primary Key I can go ahead and use the `FilterExpression` to match to the exact `list` value `["Action", "Biography"]`:

```
var params = {
    TableName : TABLE_NAME,
    KeyConditionExpression: "#yr = :yyyy",
    FilterExpression: "info.genres = :genres",
    ExpressionAttributeNames:{
        "#yr": "year"
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":yyyy": 2013,
        ":genres": ["Action", "Biography"]
    }     
};
```

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");
var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();


let promise = docClient.query(params).promise();
promise.then(res => {
console.log("res:", res);
})
```

Instead of matching an entire list `["Action", "Biography"]` I would rather make a query to return only those table items that contain a string "Biography" in a list stored in the item's `info.genres` field. I wonder if this possible using DynamoDB `query` API?

#### Edited later.

Working solution (Thanks to Balu) is to use `QueryFilter` `contains` comparison operator:

```
var params = {
    TableName: TABLE_NAME,
    Limit: 20,
    KeyConditionExpression: "id = :yyyy",
    FilterExpression: `contains(info.genres , :qqqq)`,
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ":qqqq": { S: "Biography" },
      ":yyyy": { N: 2013 },
    },
  }

let promise = docClient.query(params).promise();
promise.then(res => {
console.log("res:", res);
})
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We can use `contains` in Filter expressions instead of `=`.

So, `"info.genres = :genres"` can be changed to `contains(info.genres , :gnOne)`

AWS is still going to query on Partition Key extract max 1 MB of data in single query before applying the filter. so, we will be charged with same RCU with or without filter expression but amount of data returned to client will be limited, so, still useful.

```
const dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB();
dynamodb.query(
  {
    TableName: "my-test-table",
    Limit: 20,
    KeyConditionExpression: "id = :yyyy",
    FilterExpression: `contains(info.genres , :gnOne)`,
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ":gnOne": { S: "Biography" },
      ":yyyy": { S: "2020" },
    },
  },
  function (err, data) {
    if (err) console.error(err);
    else console.log("dynamodb scan succeeded:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
  }
);
```

Comment: can you rewrite the same for this below one, really stuck
[
  {
    "M": {
      "emailAddress": {
        "S": "mk065005"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "M": {
      "emailAddress": {
        "S": "mansish"
      }
    }
  }
]

Answer (score 3):

Short answer, no. DDB allows to store `key:val` pairs so your element which you want to query upon should be the top element.

Long answer, yes. However, it is using scan. Honestly, I don't see much difference between query and scan as far as RCUs consumption is concerned. You can use `Limit` param to limit your RCUs use in a single network call.

If we are good till now, you can use [Document Paths](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.Attributes.html#Expressions.Attributes.NestedElements.DocumentPathExamples) in your Filter Expression to achieve what you're trying to do. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32235474/dynamodb-nested-query-support) stack overflow post, and [this](https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-document-js-sdk/issues/43#issuecomment-137988852) github example.

However, **note** that this is a Scan operation, not a query, and it might turn out to be very expensive as it will not use any indices and will iterate over every document in your table.

It would be best to pull these attributes out into the top-level document, and query accordingly with a secondary index.