# Can I index and query against a field that holds a collection of values in Amazon's DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

Is this type of indexed query available in Amazon's DynamoDB?

(Where the field being searched against is a collection of values?)

Example object being indexed:

```
Restaurant: {
     name: 'Bobs Burgers'
     menu: ['hamburger', 'hotdog', 'lasagna']
}
```

Example pseudo-query:

```
SELECT * FROM restaurants WHERE menu='hamburger'
( or perhaps: 'hamburger' in menu )
```

Also:

- What is this type of index called? Its been a while since I worked
  with this kind of thing and I have forgotten some of the correct
  verbiage.
- What is a good place to get a primer on what types of queries are possible with DynamoDB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no index to find a value in a list. You can use a filter, but it won't be index-optimized. See [How to query DynamoDB filtering by value in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65695788/how-to-query-dynamodb-filtering-by-value-in-a-list)

Alex DeBrie's YouTube channel has videos on getting started with DynamoDB: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC8uIi5eIEI2_NZGTyPXTnLA

Comment: Thank you this is very helpful. Do you have an idea of what a good way to deal with this use case is? This type of query should be possible in O(log N) time with NoSQL since an index can be created that is keyed against the elements in the list. But it sounds like I would actually have to handle this in code if I were to use DynamoDB? Should I be using Amazon RDS instead for this type of data?

Comment: You can insert additional items where the partition key is ‘hamburger’ and the sort key is the restaurant name(s). Then it will be extremely efficient to find all restaurant names having a tag. Works well for this case. As you start wanting arbitrary constraints it gets more complex as you end up really “gardening” your indexes. RDS has more indexing choices but isn’t as easy to scale with predictable performance.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! It sounds like you are suggesting to use code to maintain an additional index including when items are modified and deleted? I think for my use case this will not make sense because labor time/complexity is the much bugger issue than scalability. Do you have an idea of the "proper" way to do this with an RDS/Relational database? I'm even having trouble finding the right search terms to google this. I did post a question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71243864/query-against-collection-attribute-using-a-managed-database-option-on-amazon

Comment: You've given one query you need to satisfy, and no other requirements. If you want NoSQL, try MongoDB or on AWS DocumentDB.

Comment: OMG thanks so much! I did not even see AWS DocumentDB. It looks like that is basically MongoDB and this type of index is possible in Mongo? Also, do you know the term for this type of index? I feel like if I searched for the right thing I would have been able to find an answer, but I had a lot of trouble expressing this question verbally.

Comment: Perhaps https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-multikey/

Answer (score 2):

No, you only can create a secondary index on scalar types which are String, Number or Binary.

It is indicated in [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/SecondaryIndexes.html) as:

> Every attribute in the index key schema must be a top-level attribute of type
> String, Number, or Binary. Other data types, including documents and
> sets, are not allowed.

The best point to get updated about aws dynamodb would be the official [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStartedDynamoDB.html) i believe. They cover almost every topic in detail.