# Query against collection attribute using a managed database option on Amazon

Tags: database-design, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora, dynamodb-queries

I would like to query for some objects in O(log N) time by a field that is a set of string values.

Example object being indexed:

```
Restaurant: {
     name: 'Bobs Burgers'
     menu: ['hamburger', 'hotdog', 'lasagna']
}
```

Example pseudo-query:

```
SELECT * FROM restaurants WHERE menu='hamburger'
( or perhaps: 'hamburger' in menu )
```

Long ago I used Google App Engine and they allowed me to do this on their NoSql database, Big Table.

However I understand that Amazon's DynamoDB does not allow me to this. I understand that if I were to use DynamoDB for this type of query, I would need to use code to maintain a secondary look-up table myself (which obviously I don't want to do). Am I correct in this assumption? Or is there a clean technique that is used to query against this kind of data in O(log N) time using a database with the limitations of DynamoDB (which is that sets/collections cannot be used in an index)

Or should I be using a different technology for this type of use case? For example Amazon RDS - which offers the following types of Databases:

- Amazon Aurora
- PostgreSQL
- MySQL
- MariaDB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS DocumentDB does this. It is MongoDB compatible.

The type of index that you are referring to is called "Multikey" in MongoDB:

"https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-multikey/"

Answer (score 1):

Here it is using schemafreesql  Saw their post on show hackers adds a nosql layer to any SQL DB. Below is a modified example from their site.

```
[
    {
        "modify": {
            "data": {
                "Restaurant": [
                    {
                        "name": "Bobs Burgers",
                        "menu": [
                            "hamburger",
                            "hotdog",
                            "lasagna"
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Sallys Burgers",
                        "menu": [
                            "eggs",
                            "french toast",
                            "danish"
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Johns Burgers",
                        "menu": [
                            "grilled cheese",
                            "hamburger",
                            "patty melt"
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            "_comment": "Create Restaurants"
        }
    },
    {
        "query": {
            "sfsql": "SELECT $s:Restaurant.name as 'Restaurant',  $s:Restaurant.menu as 'menu' where $s:Restaurant.menu='hamburger'",
            "_comment": "Query Restaurant by menu"
        }
    }
    
]
```

Comment: This is really interesting. Do you know why someone would use this instead of a document database like MongoDB / Amazon Document DB?

Comment: it's an enhancemen to your SQL database instead of having to move to a entire new persistent storage. Also it's a schemaless Objects Store not a document store or key . value store. The json is used as a Data format only, behind the scenes referenceable objects are created from the json submitted. You mayy still use your db as you normally would. everything is kept in its own table space. Hosted version is currently offered self hosted is coming soon.

Comment: Also failed to mention with SFSQL you get a sql like language and  all the aggregate functions that come with the  underlying DB.